# Typical output lag value for a Windows desktop PC?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, hardware

How many milliseconds typically passes from the moment I’ve changed a visual tree in my WPF app (hidden or shown an element), to the moment when physical image is changed as the result of that?

The hardware — typical desktop PC, Intel GPU, HDMI cable delivering FullHD @ 60Hz, mid-range DLP projector.

Comment: My guess is it's probably less than a millisecond.

Comment: @Kevin_ The latency is at least 17ms, because HDMI delivers 60 frames per second. What I don't know is how much latency bring the rest of my stack: WPF, Direct3D9, GPU driver + hardware, and the projector.